# Solve the equation: $x^3+7x^2+16x+5=(1-2x)\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

Solve the equation: $x^3+7x^2+16x+5=(1-2x)\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}$

---

I used wolframalpha.com and get the solution: $x\in\{-3;2\sqrt2-3\}$

When $x=-3$, $\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}=-1$

When $x=2\sqrt2-3$, $\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}=2\sqrt2-1$

So I guess we can prove that: $x+2=\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}$

I tried to use function method (use function's monotonous) but didn't get any result.

Comment: where did you get this????????

Comment: $x=0 , x+2 \neq {(-3x²-7x+5)}^{(1/3)}$ .they are not the same .

Comment: $x = -3-2 \sqrt{2}$ seems to fit too.

Comment: and no theoritical way to solve equation that have deg>=3 , Galois theory ,only numerical method  (iteratives methods ) .or only way to make a transformation to your equation as a simple dynamical system with initial conditions

Comment: pleas verifie your solutions i don't think that you  have 3 real solution, i think you have 1 real solution and 2 complex : $x_{1}=2\sqrt(2) -3$ and $x_{2}=-3.99+3.26i $ ,$x_{3}=-3.99 -3.26i$

Comment: -3 is not a solution, pleas verifie

Comment: Because $-3x^2-7x+5$ may be negative so $-3$ is also a solution.

Comment: may negative not sure , and pleas do sibstitution by x=-3 in the LHSA and RHS of your equation and see if they are the same .

Comment: and determine  in where you solve your equation in R or C or Z ,

Comment: It's considered here $\sqrt[3]{x}=-\sqrt[3]{|x|}$ when $x<0$, IMHO. @zeraouliarafik

Comment: but who  assure to you that the RHS be negative ? do you have a reason ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik " no theoritical way to solve equation that have deg>=3" that is not true. First of all there is a formula for the quartic and you can solve *some* polynomials of degree $\geq5$... (but not all, yes.)

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3+7x^2+16x+5=(1-2x)\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}$$
The roots of the above equation belong to the set of roots of the next equation :
$$(x^3+7x^2+16x+5)^3=(1-2x)^3(-3x^2-7x+5)$$
Expanding and factoring lead to :
$$(x+3)(x^2+6x+1)P(x)=0$$
where $P(x)=x^6+12x^5+68x^4+187x^3+295x^2+159x+40$

$P(x)=\left(x^3+6x^2+16x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+69\left(x+\frac{40}{69}\right)^2+\frac{2915}{276}$

The three terms are positive. Hense $P(x)>0$ any $x$.

So the real roots of the initial equation could only be among the roots of $(x+3)(x^2+6x+1)=0$
$$\begin{cases}
     x_1=-3\\
     x_2=-3+2\sqrt{2}\\
     x_3=-3-2\sqrt{2}
   \end{cases}$$
Bringing back those possible roots into the initial equation, we observe that the three are convenient. Hense the initial equation has the three above 
real roots.

Note : This is in considering the real cubic root of $-1$, that is : $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$ :
$$\sqrt[3]{-3x^2-7x+5}=-\sqrt[3]{3x^2+7x-5}$$

The figure below is the graphical representation of the equation and roots.

[image]